# Realm IO v0.88.+ - Get Primary Key Column Name

Tags: android, realm

On prior versions of Realm IO I used the following code to get the Primary Key Column name:

```
Table table = realm.getTable(<class name>);
long primaryKeyColumnIndex = table.getPrimaryKey();
String primaryKeyColumnName = table.getColumnName(primaryKeyColumnIndex);
```

With the recent release I noticed that Realm.getTable has been depreciated. I want to migrate my code over to use `realm.getSchema` however I have been unable to work out how to get the primary key column name (if it exists).

Any help would be gratefully received!
Gavin

Comment: I guess we missed this when making new dynamic API. An issue is created for this https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2440

Comment: Nice Beeender. Do you want to post an answer (referencing v0.89 or Realm IO) so that I can mark as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new API `RealmObjectSchema.isPrimaryKey()` has been added for this purpose. We somehow missed that when making Dynamic API.

It will be released in Realm-java v0.89.0, the relevant PR is https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2445 . Before the v0.89.0 gets released, you can use the snapshot release to get this new API.

Thanks for pointing that out!